# Cannot make a pointer to user defined class but i can directly instantiate it

Tags: c++

I have a class named HUD and whenever I write

```
HUD *hud = new HUD(screenwidth,screenHight);
```

I get this error

> missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

but if I directly instantiate it

```
Hud hud(screenwidth,screenHight);
```

it works fine, how can i fix this problem
here is cpp for the code

```
HUD::HUD(float windowWidth,float windowHeight){

    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf");
    time.setFont(font);
    time.setColor(Color::White);
    time.setPosition(Vector2f(windowWidth/2,VERTICAL_INDENTATION));
    time.setCharacterSize(FONT_SIZE);

    coinIcon.loadFromFile(COIN_ICON);
    coinDisplay.setTexture(&coinIcon);
    coinDisplay.setSize(Vector2f(20,20));
    coinDisplay.setPosition(Vector2f(0,VERTICAL_INDENTATION));

    coins.setFont(font);
    coins.setColor(Color::White);
    coins.setPosition(Vector2f(HORIZONTAL_INDENTATION,VERTICAL_INDENTATION));
    coins.setCharacterSize(FONT_SIZE);

    numOfCoins = 0;
}


void HUD::startClock(){
    clock.restart();
}

// returns seconds to the nearest digit
int HUD::getTimeElapsed(){
    return (int)(0.5+clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds());
}

void HUD::incrementCoins(){
    numOfCoins++;
}

int HUD::getNumOfCoins(){
    return numOfCoins;
}
// only accepts positive numbers
std::string HUD::toString(int num){
    std::string str("");
    char digit;
    while(num%10 != 0){
        digit = '0'+num%10;
        str.insert(0,1,digit);
        num /= 10;
    }
    if(str.size() == 0)
        str = "0";
    return str;
}

void HUD::render(RenderWindow *window){
    coins.setString(toString(numOfCoins));
    time.setString(toString((int)(0.5+clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds())));

    window->draw(coinDisplay);
    window->draw(coins);
    window->draw(time);
}
```

and this is the header file

```
using namespace sf;

#define COIN_ICON "Textures/coin.png"
#define VERTICAL_INDENTATION 20
#define HORIZONTAL_INDENTATION 20
#define FONT_SIZE 30

class HUD{
    RectangleShape coinDisplay;
    Texture coinIcon;
    Text coins;
    int numOfCoins;

    sf::Clock clock;
    Text time;

    std::string toString(int num);
public:
    HUD(float windowWidth,float windowHeight);
    ~HUD(void);
    void startClock();
    int restartClock();
    void render(RenderWindow *window);
    int getTimeElapsed();
    void incrementCoins();
    int getNumOfCoins();
};
```

Comment: Karim, you should really give _complete_ code that compiles so that we're not having to guess. First you mistyped the declaration, now you're using a type `Hud` that doesn't even exist (the type is `HUD`) and there's nowhere near enough code in the question to try and compile without a massive effort.. Voting to close as incomplete, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a pointer, because you are not asking for one.

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
HUD* hud = new HUD(screenwidth,screenHight);
```

The difference between that and :

```
HUD hud;
```

Is that the former instantiates the object on the heap, while the latter instantiates the object on the stack.  You will have to be sure to call:

```
delete hud;
```

if you choose to instantiate with the first method.

Comment: i have it written in my code as you said. i mistyped it when i was writing the question.i get this error

missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for declaring a pointer is:

```
HUD* hud = new HUD(screenwidth,screenHight);
```

But then again, you should not use naked pointers where possible. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

**Edit**

I noticed you wrote that it works when you declare the type as `Hud` instead of `HUD`. I suspect there is a typo here.

Comment: i have it written in my code as you said. i mistyped it when i was writing the question.i get this error

missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: @KarimMohamedHasebou Edited my answer. Please check. Anyway to summarize: you use different type specifier in your working code. Is the type supposed to be `Hud` or `HUD`?

Comment: is it HUD and i tried instantiating it directy without a pointer and it compiles. but when i try using a pointer it refuses

Comment: What is the error now? As @paxdiablo said, the error should not come from the `HUD*` declaration now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the source of the problem. the problem was that in the project i used a header called common that included all headers in the project and included common in each cpp file. for some reason even though HUD is included in common it still didnt work till i included HUD.h in the header file declaring the pointer HUD